# click gridview item and editext gets focus

Tags: android, gridview, android-edittext

I have displayed a gridview whose items are a textview and edittext.Now ,how to  achieve function that I click the gridview item and the edittext get the focus?

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
```

how to override this function?
I try that before:

```
((EditText)gridview.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.grid_edittext)).requestFocus();
```

and also:

```
((ViewGroup)gridview.getChildAt(position)).getChildAt(1).requestFocus();
```

There adds a System.out.printlen("hello");
in onitemclick function,but it doesn't show up in logcat.

Is there any samples??

Comment: on ItemClick method of Gridview , call requestFocus method of EditText

Comment: I did that but didn't work

Comment: on itemclick event u use onfocus listener on Edittext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get `EditText` from `AdapterView` and set `requestFocus()` as below. This may be work.

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
            EditText edittext = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_edittext);
            edt.setFocusable(true);
            edittext.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            if (edittext.requestFocus()) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.showSoftInput(edittext, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
            }
      }
   });
```

**EDIT:**
Set `focusable` and `focusableInTouchMode` to **`false`** for `EditText` as below:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: I tried it also.But it didn't work.Maybe some settings are wrong.

Comment: make sure your EditText is focusable

Comment: try editText.peformClick(); (unless you don't want the keyboard to show up)

Comment: Thank you!It worked.But after inputting several edittext,it doesn't work.

Comment: For this, you have to set **`edittext.setFocusable(false)`** & **`edittext.setFocusableInTouchMode(false)`** for all positions except the position you have clicked.

Answer (score 0):

When Using gridView, TextView and EditText should not have the flag

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

unless you want a foreign focus behavior, you can use instead

```
 android:lines="1",
```

don't ask me why! it's kind of android OS bug,
Hope this will help,